# Function creates additional wrong item of selectpicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a function to update **Bootstrap** `selectpicker`:

```
function LoadProductDetailings() {
    var productId = $(this).val();
    $('.product-detailing').find('option').remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ProductDetailings", "Task")',
        data: 'ProductId=' + productId,
        success: function (response) {
            var detailings = JSON.parse(response);

            if (detailings != null) {

                for (var i = 0; i < detailings.length; ++i) {
                    var det = detailings[i];
                    $('.product-detailing').append('<option value="' + det.Id + '">' + det.Name + '</option>');
                }

                $('.product-detailing').selectpicker("refresh");
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('@Errors.ActionFailed');
        },
        timeout: 15000
    });
}
```

But it generates one yet additional item:
[image: Screenshot]

How to fix it?

Comment: @LaurIvan, sorry, unfortunately, I can't by our inner rules in company

Answer (score 2):

Your selector

`$('.product-detailing').append('<option...>');`

Appends to every element with class `product-detailing`. You have a `<div>` and a `<select>` with that class.

Change your selector to

`$('select.product-detailing').append('<option...>');`

so that it only targets the `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are probably looping it for 1 more time than required in your for loop:

you can try doing this :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < detailings.length - 1; ++i) {
     var det = detailings[i];
     $('.product-detailing').append('<option value="' + det.Id + '">' + det.Name + '</option>');
 }
```

Comment: Loop passes 1 iteration only